# Script error 0x80020101 calling ActiveX script in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: javascript, c#, dll, activex, activexobject

I'm using the following code to call C# DLL functions. This .htm file runs on top of a plugin application that is launched via C# DLL. In the code I am trying to load the DLL using the GUID of the DLL. This code works already on all Windows OS except Windows 2012 R2. What could be the issue?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script language="javascript">

function OnLoad()
{
  xyzFactory.CreateXYZ(obj);   
}

</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body onload="OnLoad()" onunload="OnUnload()" scroll="no" leftmargin=0 
topmargin=0 BOTTOMMARGIN=0 RIGHTMARGIN=0>
<OBJECT id="xyzFactory"
    classid=clsid:<<guid>> VIEWASTEXT>
</OBJECT>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: this is client-side code. is it relevant? as I would not expect any end user to run it in the browser on a server OS. how exactly is the original classid line built? as you show it, it seems to suffer from a < > mismatch. tags have capitalization mismatch. attribute values are sometimes in quotes, sometimes not.

Comment: We are launching an application (say ABC) written in a different language from C++ application through a C# bridge. In the code we are getting handle to the bridge via the script and in the C# DLL launching the second application. I have provided a snippet. This code works in other windows OS except 2012 R2

Comment: understood. but how is it embedded? in a browser, a Webbrowser control, on a C# windows form or from MFC, ...?

Comment: It's from MFC application. This application talks to the "plugins" (legacy or web application) through ActiveX API

Comment: log on as the same user that encounters the error, on the 2012 R2 machine. open the HTML page in the default browser. it should show the actual script error (0x80020101 is just the notification that the JScript engine has reported _any_ script error to the scripting host, and does not point to the underlying exception).

Comment: and if that does not help, wrap the `CreateXYZ` call in a try...catch block and see if the error goes away. If it does, narrow down by evaluating the JavaScript exception in the catch block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @dlatikay. I guess this is the problem:  I get "object doesn't support this property or method" calling the activex API. I see that the Active X control is there in the Add on (as 32 bit). I am using IE11 64 bit (Same combination works on Win 7, Win 2008 R2).